# Contents of GSList change during loop to read file

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I'm writing a small program to analyze columns in a CSV file. The first line of the file contains headings, which I store in a `GSList`. The list contains the correct character arrays after reading the first line in the file, but after reading the second line the same list contains garbage.

```c
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile.csv", "r");
char *csv_line;
size_t max_number_characters = 1000;
size_t len = 0;

csv_line = (char *)g_malloc(max_number_characters * sizeof(char));

/* Declare GSList */
GSList *headings = NULL;
gboolean on_first_line = TRUE;

while (getline(&csv_line, &len, fp) != -1) {
    if (on_first_line) {
        headings = make_headings(csv_line);
        on_first_line = FALSE;
        /* Retrieve the second element in the GSList */
        gchar *key = strdup((gchar *)g_slist_nth_data(headings, 1));
        g_print("The key is %s\n", key); /* prints 'fiscal_year' as expected */
    } else {
        /* Retrieve the second element in the GSList */
        gchar *key = strdup((gchar *)g_slist_nth_data(headings, 1));
        g_print("The key is %s\n", key); /* prints unitialized garbage' */
    }
}
```

Why do the contents of `GSList` change?

Answer (score 0):

As so often happens, the answer came to me after posting the question to SO. In my function `make_headings` I was adding to the `GSList` memory locations within the character array `csv_line`. The next time the loop read a string into `csv_line` the values within the `GSList` changed!